# 'Bad boolean filter input.' for entitlement process in Change Set

Tags: change-set

When deploying a change set, I am getting "Bad boolean filter input." error. All milestones are included and this is the only error out of a changeset with 1500 components.

Can't find anything online related to this, a google search for "Bad boolean filter input." doesn't return anything.

[image: Change Set Screenshot]

Comment: Are you doing something like deploying a report that uses a field that is not in the change set?

Comment: Try using this search engine that's salesforce specific:  http://findsf.info/

Comment: @Jagular - all reports have deployed fine, it's just the entitlement processes that have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone needs this, your Milestone Criteria in the Entitlement Process cannot have the advanced filter logic for the change set.  If there is advanced filter logic, the change set will fail.  Just create the Milestone Criteria with all ANDs (no filter logic) and then when you get to production, change to the filtering (AND / OR) that you need.

Answer (score 2):

The error was caused by referencing a picklist value in the exit criteria of the Entitlement Process that didn't exist in the target org.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the scope of [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008c2nAAA) is broader than described in the KI. Complex filter logic in entitlement process makes process undeployable to target orgs.

The KI suggests ambiguously that filters on Case Record Type are the issue, or that the filters 'contains' and 'does not contain' are to be avoided. The error message 'Bad Boolean' appears.

However I find that straightforward logic like (1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4) throws this message and deployment fails, with both change sets and the Force.com IDE.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43509)

Comment: It does not provide an answer,  but it provides significant clarification to an relevant Known Issue which suffers from ambiguity and a misleadingly narrow scope.

Comment: "To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post"